# jQuery slideUp().remove() doesn't seem to show the slideUp animation before remove occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this line of JavaScript and the behavior I am seeing is that the `selectedLi` instantly disappears without "sliding up".  This is not the behavior that I expected.

What should I be doing so that the `selectedLi` slides up before it is removed?

```
selectedLi.slideUp("normal").remove();
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Might be able to fix it by putting the call to remove in a callback arg to slideUp?

e.g

```
selectedLi.slideUp("normal", function() { $(this).remove(); } );
```

Comment: Note that "slow" and "fast" are the only speeds.  Other speeds need to either be in milliseconds or they will default to 400. http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/#speeds

Answer (score 22):

You need to be more explicit: rather than saying "this" (which I agree should work), you should do this:

```
$("#yourdiv").slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: SORRY = i forgot to remove my id, should be:                                                               $('#yourdiv').slideUp(1000, function(){ $('#yourdiv').remove(); });

Comment: Using $(this) instead of $("#yourdiv") is more optimized since jQuery does not need to look for a node.

Comment: Using `$("#yourdiv")` instead of `$(this)` is completely redundant and that's not why this code fixes OP's problem. This code fixes the problem because it uses the `complete` callback.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is calling the "remove()" function inside slideUp as a parameter like others have said, as this example:

```
$("#yourdiv").slideUp("normal", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

It is a must to call it inside the anonymous function() to prevent remove() to be executed before the slideUp has ended. Another equal way is to use the jQuery function "promise()". Better for those who like self-explanatory code, like me ;)

```
$("#yourdiv").slideUp("normal").promise().done(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using promises you can also wait for multiple animations to get finished, e.g.:

```
selectedLi.slideUp({duration: 5000, queue: false})
.fadeOut({duration: 3000, queue: false})
.promise().done(function() {
    selectedLi.remove()
})
```

Answer (score -3):

```
selectedLi.slideUp(200, this.remove);
```

Comment: I tested - it doesn't remove element after sliding up.

Comment: Effecively hides the element, but does not actually remove it from the DOM.