# Can jQuery detach() or appendTo() use with toggle/animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-plugins, toggle

```
$('#step1').eq(1).detach().appendTo('#tmp');
$('#step2').detach().appendTo('.content');
```

I have a div holder `class="content"`, when click a button, `#step1` detached, and append to a temple div `#tmp`, `#step2` detach from some other place and append to `<div class="content">`

Is there any way to use detach combine with animate or toggle?

I tried `.animate({width:'toggle'},2000)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See this question and the top answer. You can put it into a callback function.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308019/jquery-slideup-remove-doesnt-seem-to-show-the-slideup-animation-before-remo

Answer (score 1):

To expand on zacechola's comment, you want to animate hiding the item, then detach/append, then animate showing it again.

So something like:

```
var element = ...
var newParent = ...
element.slideup('normal', function() {
    element.detach().appendTo(newParent);
    element.slidedown('normal');
});
```